# Configuring the MaxMind license in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, maxmind

The client has purchased a MaxMind license and I have received a license number.  I have also been able to verify the license by hitting the MaxMind webservice directly.  However, I have not been able to find anywhere in the configuration to put the license number.

I found the following line in `Sitecore.Analytics.config` which looks promising but am not sure if I should simply replace the `{1}` with my license number.  Is this the right place to do this?

```
<setting name="MaxMind.Url" value="http://sitecore1.maxmind.com/app/sc?i={0}&amp;l={1}" />
```

For reference, some of my custom business logic is based on the visitor's geolocation, here is some sample code:

```
var cv = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.CurrentVisit;
var lat = cv.Latitude;
var lng = cv.Longitude;
```

However `lat` and `lng` almost come out as 0 - which is when I realized we need the license.

Sitecore.NET 6.5 (rev. 121009)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a setting in `sitecore/includes/Sitecore.Analytics.config`

```
<!--  MAXMIND SECURITY TOKEN
    Security token from MaxMind.
    Default: "00000000"
-->
<setting name="MaxMind.SecurityToken" value="00000000" />
```

Set the value to your purchased license (using a patch:config).

http://www.theinsidecorner.com/en/Marketers/SitecoreDMS/EngagementAnalytics/MaxMindSettings

Comment: Sir, I will try this right now!  My token is much longer than that but it's all numeric so it makes sense.

Comment: This didn't work for me... I'm going to do some debugging and see what's up.  Thanks again @jammykam

Comment: turns out the geoip for my test cases were cached, the security token did the trick.